# Gatsby GraphQL React

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

since I was using a little bit Apollo with Graphql, apollo query provide 'loading' where I can simply render some loader by checking loading state.

While Iam using Gatsby and useStaticQuery hook I cant get any 'loading' state, is that possible to check it somehow? or maybe there is other hook than useStaticQuery? Someone could please explain me that thing?

Comment: Please edit your post title to ask a clear question instead of listing software tags. Also, most questions on SO require code. Please show some.

Comment: Query results are evaluated on build time and hence you don't need loading state. There is reason its called staticquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gatsby runs queries on build time and replaces them with JSON file imports later which is why there is not need for a loading state as the queries already have data for them

According to [`Gatsby documentation`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-vs-normal-queries/#adding-imports-for-page-data)

> Code that is specific for querying the GraphQL server set up during
>   build time is no longer relevant, and can be swapped out in exchange
>   for the JSON data that has been extracted for each query.
>
> The imports related to GraphQL and query declarations are changed to
>   imports for the JSON that correspond to the query result that Gatsby
>   found when it ran the query

For example, the below component

```
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"
export () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
      siteMetadata {
        site {
            title
        }
      }
  `)
  return (
    <h1>
        {data.siteMetadata.site.title}
    </h1>
  )
}
```

will be overriden with the below code post the build

```
import dataJson from `/d/<hash>.json`
export () => {
  const data = dataJson
  return (
    <h1>
        {data.siteMetadata.site.title}
    </h1>
  )
}
```

Comment: Sure I understand this logic, but same happen when u want to fetch data from external Api ?

Comment: external API's used with useStaticQueries of PageQueries will all be compiled at build time. Any change in data will need them to trigger a rebuild